# Parameterized animation in Angular2

Tags: animation, angular, css-transitions, transition

Is it possible to parameterize animation using built in mechanism (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html)?

For example I would like to create `accordion component` and allow consumer of this component to define how fast content of accordion should appear/disappear.

ex.
`<accordion [transitionTime]="150ms">...</accordion>`

And hypothetical usage of transitionTime:

```
animations: [
  trigger("state", [
    state("A", //style),
    state("B", //style),
    transition("A => B", animate(dynamic.transitionTime + "ms ease-in-out")),
    transition("B => A", animate(dynamic.transitionTime + "ms ease-in-out"))
  ])
]
```